# Delphi 2009: OnMouseEnter, OnMouseLeave AND Enabled

Tags: delphi

I have made a `MyButton` component inherit from `Class(TPanel)`. The component changes appearance in connection with `OnMouseEnter`, `OnMouseLeave`, `OnMouseDown`, `OnMouseUp` and `ENABLED`.

This is some code for `ENABLED`:

I use standard `CMMouseEnter(var msg: TMessage)` and `CMMouseLeave(var msg: TMessage)`:

Immediately everything seems OK. All events trigger as they should. Except for one situation:

When I place 2 MyButtons on a Form (`MyBut1` and `MyBut2`) and write this code in the Click-Events:

```
MyBut1.Click(Sender): MyBut1.Enabled:=False //!!!
```

Everything Ok. (Disables its own component)

```
MyBut2.Click(Sender): MyBut1.Enabled:=True //!!!
```

Works fine, but CMMouseEnter and CMMouseLeave dos not trigger Subsequently. All other events works fine.

I hope this description is enough information and I hope that somebody can help me out.

```
Private
  FOnMouseLeave: TNotifyEvent;
  FOnMouseEnter: TNotifyEvent;
  procedure CMMouseEnter(var msg: TMessage); message CM_MOUSEENTER;
  procedure CMMouseLeave(var msg: TMessage); message CM_MOUSELEAVE;
Protected
  procedure SetEnabled(aEnab: Boolean); override;
published
  property OnMouseEnter: TNotifyEvent read FOnMouseEnter write FOnMouseEnter;
  property OnMouseLeave: TNotifyEvent read FOnMouseLeave write FOnMouseLeave;
Procedure TMyButton.SetEnabled(aEnab: Boolean);
  Begin
  Inherited;
  If aEnab=False Then Begin
    //Do Somtiing
  End
  Else Begin
    //Do Somthing else
  End;
  If Not Locked Then Invalidate;
End;
procedure TMyButton.CMMouseEnter(var msg: TMessage);
begin
  //Call to DoMouseEnter;
end;
procedure TMyButton.CMMouseLeave(var msg: TMessage);
begin
  //Call to DoMouseLeave;
end;
```

Comment: Why do you inherit from `TPanel`?

Comment: >Andreas: This id only an Example, It could be somthing else.

Comment: This is only an examble. It could be something else . why not TPanel?

Comment: The characteristic thing about the panel is that you can drop other controls onto it. But surely you don't want to drop other controls on your button? It would make more sense to have your button class be a child class of `TCustomControl` or `TCustomButton`.

Comment: That make sense. I tried TCustomControl - unfortunately same problem.